# Knockedout by knockout

Tags: jquery, knockout.js

It´s getting late, so I´m probably both stupid and blind, but I have been struggling with this for a while. Can anybody see what is wrong here?

My HTML:

```
<select data-bind="options: Tasks, optionsText: 'TaskName', value: SelectedTask"></select>
<button data-bind="click: newTask">Add New Text</button>

<div data-bind="with: SelectedTask, visible: showEditor()">   
    <div>
        Taskname: <input data-bind="value: TaskName" />
    </div>
</div>
```

The ViewModel:

```
Type.registerNamespace("myNameSpace");

myNameSpace.Task = function (data) {
    var self = this;
    self.TaskId = data.TaskId;
    self.TaskName = ko.observable(data.TaskName);
}; 

myNameSpace.ViewModel = function () {
    var self = this;

    self.SelectedTask = ko.observable();
    self.Tasks = ko.observableArray();
    self.showEditor = ko.observable(false);

    $.getJSON("/myService/GetAllTasks", function (allData) {
        var mappedTasks = $.map(allData, function (item) {
            return new myNameSpace.Task(item)
        });
        self.Tasks(mappedTasks); 
    });

    self.newTask = function () {
        var newitem = new myNameSpace.Task({
            TaskId: -1,
            TaskName: "...your task title..."
        });
        self.Tasks.push(newitem);      
        self.editTask(newitem);
    };

    self.editTask = function (item) { 
        self.SelectedTask(item);   // My program stops executing on this line
        self.showEditor(true);       
    };

}; // End of ViewModel
```

This codes fails on "self.SelectedTask(item);" and I can´t figure out why.
The getJSON that fills self.Tasks() returns nothing as the db-table is empty. (could this be part of the problem?)

What I want is to edit the TaskName after the "click:newTask" event has fired. The new Task is pushed to my array of Tasks and I set my editor visible to type in the Taskname of the SelectedTask - which should be the one just created in "newTask".

Fiddle here: http://jsfiddle.net/dL3JB/2/

Comment: `newitem` is out of scope there, the var is defined in `.newTask`.

Comment: your fiddle throws a error

Comment: Just updated my answer after sleeping and nemesv's input :)

Comment: i got this error in console ReferenceError: Type is not defined
 

Type.registerNamespace("myNameSpace");

Answer (score 2):

`newitem` is out of scope there, the `var` is defined in `.newTask`.

What you should do, as [nemesv](https://stackoverflow.com/users/872395/nemesv)  sugested, is use the fact that you pass `newitem` as a parameter when you call `editTask` and use `item` inside `editTask`.

```
self.SelectedTask(item);   // instead of self.SelectedTask(newitem);
```

[**FIDDLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/XEJ3S/)

Comment: Yeah the problem is that the `newitem` is not available in `editTask` but at solution is to change `self.SelectedTask(newitem);` to `self.SelectedTask(item);` and not moving `newitem` outside of `newTask`... because your fiddle works incorrectly it always add the same item to the `Tasks` so if you edit one item all the items get edited...

Comment: @nemesv, true! I was tired last night. Corrected that, thank you.

Comment: Thanks for the fiddle and pointing the bug out. Haven't been able to test it yet, but fear it's not this simple (hope I am wrong), as part of my testing I moved the self.SelectedTask(newitem) from editTask to newTask and it still failed. I fear the "newitem"-bug in my post here comes from that testing. I will come vack with an update when I'm avle to test.

Comment: Unfortunately I can confirm now that the out of context "new item" is not the key to my trouble. self.SelectedTask(item) fails also.

Comment: @AsleG, does my fiddle do what you want? And do you still get a error on same line after the correction?